# How to import and use C++ .dll in python (visual studio code)

Tags: python, c++, gcc, dll

I have this .dll from c++ for reedsolomon fec but all my other work is done on python. how do  i bridge this gap?
I looked up chatgpt, youtube and ussed gcc to  no avail
In Visual Studio Code, integrating a C++ DLL into a Python project involves several steps to ensure seamless interoperability between the two languages. Initially, you must create a C++ DLL, compile it using a suitable compiler like MinGW, and organize your project directory.

For Visual Studio Code, configure a `tasks.json` file within the `.vscode` folder to define a build task for compiling the C++ code. This task specifies the compiler, compilation flags, and the output path for the generated DLL. Trigger this build task using the provided shortcuts (Ctrl + Shift + B or Cmd + Shift + B) to compile the DLL seamlessly within the editor.

After successfully building the C++ DLL, write a Python script within the same project to utilize the DLL's functionality. Use the `ctypes` module to load the DLL dynamically and call its functions. Ensure that the DLL path is correctly specified in the Python script.

Finally, execute the Python script through the Visual Studio Code debugger or terminal, ensuring that the Python interpreter can locate both the DLL and the Python script. This streamlined integration allows for efficient collaboration between C++ and Python components within the Visual Studio Code environment, facilitating a cohesive development experience.
none oof this works

Comment: So it looks like you know what to do as you have enumerated all the steps. What's the problem then? "It doesn't work" is not a description of a problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: all these solutions are good on paper but do not work first hand, that is why I came here

Comment: What's the problem with "It does not work"? It does not work. Try asking a specific question about a specific error you are struggling with. Something like this could be a good format. "I'm trying to follow this procedure (*link*). At step (*number*), I type this command (*quotation*), and get this error message (*quotation*) instead of this expected success message (*quotation*)".

Comment: what I meant was that I tried the upper solution to no avail, try suggesting something else if anyone else has gone through the same trouble.

Comment: I can give you a suggestion: use pybind11. But how well it will work for you, I have no idea.